# get elements from html parser

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm using JSOUP, and trying to get the elements which start with a particular div tag id. For example:

```
<div id="test123">.
```

I need to check if the elements starts with the string "test" and get all the elements.

I looked at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax and I tried a multiple variations using:

```
doc.select("div:matches(test(*))");
```

But it still didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: :matches() does a regex on the element's text content, not the element's attributes. [attr~=regex] is for attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attribute-starts-with selector `[attr^=value]`.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div[id^=test]");
// ...
```

This will return all `<div>` elements with an `id` attribute starting with `test`.