# GWT get elements by Id and regex

Tags: regex, gwt, search

I need to get (by Id) all the elements on a document that match a given regex with GWT. I know I can iterate through all of the elements in the document and collect those that match the regex, but I want to avoid doing that.

Can you think of another solution?

Comment: I do not know a better solution in javascript. Hence, there is no better solution in GWT.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, but there doesn't seem to be a GWT implementaion for it...

[get elements from html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950804/get-elements-from-html-parser)

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: If there's no GWT implementation of it, then it won't work for me.